# Granting my access permissions to everyone?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, chmod

If folder `folder` is read/write/execute accessible to me, then it should become read/write/execute to everyone.
Calling `chmod -R 777 ./folder` does not suit, because it makes *all* files executable, even those that were not executable before.
Is there an easy way?

Comment: How come `chmod -R 777 ./foler` does not make the files be accessible, in addition to being executable?

Comment: @AvihooMamka it does too much: it makes read/write only files to be also executable, which is not desirable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add add the files in the folder to a user group like `everyone` or `users` depending on your distro.

`chown -R <youruser>:everyone ./folder`

You can check what available user groups you have with `groups` command.

Comment: Note: this is a pragmatic simple way, but you need to have `sudo` rights. @cms's answer below avoids this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with UNIX [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) combined with the exec flag to run a chmod command on every file that matches a filter, and filter on the executable bit.

e.g.

first find the non executable files recursively and change them to all RW

```
find ./folder -not -executable -exec chmod a=rw {} \;
```

then find all the executable ones recursively and change them to all RWX

```
find ./folder -executable -exec chmod a=rwx {} \;
```

Comment: in contrast to @Lucho's answer, your script assigns the same rwx accesses as the file _owner_ has, right? (vs. rwx accesses of the file _group_). I think we might also need to refine for read-only and write-only accesses (otherwise scripts might change read-only to read-write).

Comment: yes, the quoted example is just for owner permissions, and is just intended as an example of using find to match and execute - you could add -group groupname to select by group, or use -perm to match on specific attribute bits